# How can I fix location of my OutLineTextField in compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-compose-textfield, android-compose-dropdownmenu

I'm trying to add an `outlinetextfield` to my screen in compose, but for some reason it always appears at the bottom. I couldn't solve this situation?

Also, as a second question,

I have two `dropwdown` menus and clicking either one always opens the list of the first `dropdown` menu. Any idea why this is? It seemed okay to me. If the first `dropdown` menu is clicked, its list will open, if the second is clicked, the second will open. This is how it should normally be.

#### Hear is my screen shots

**As you can see In the first picture, a small part of the outlinedtextfield is visible at the bottom.**

**in the second picture there is a picture of the dropdown menu problem**

[image]

[image]

**my code**

```
 @Composable
fun ExchangeMainScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: ExchangeMainViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {


    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(3.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {

        DropDownMenu()
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))
        OutLineTextFieldSample()
    }

   
}

@Composable
fun OutLineTextFieldSample() {

    var text by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp),
        Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        OutlinedTextField(
            label = {
                Text(
                    text = "Enter currency amount",
                    style = TextStyle(
                        color = MaterialTheme.colors.primaryVariant,
                    )
                )
            },
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
                focusedBorderColor = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary,
                unfocusedBorderColor = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary,
                focusedLabelColor = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary,
                cursorColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primaryVariant
            ),

            value = text,
            onValueChange = { text = it },
        )

    }


}

@Composable
fun DropDownMenu() {


    var expanded1 by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var expanded2 by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    var selectedItem1 by remember { mutableStateOf("Select Item") }
    var selectedItem2 by remember { mutableStateOf("Select Item") }

    val itemList1 = listOf(
        "USD", "TRY", "EUR", "AMD", "AFN", "BGN"
    )
    val itemList2 = listOf(
        "USD", "TRY", "EUR", "AMD", "AFN", "BGN"
    )

    Column(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(vertical = 20.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
        Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {

        Box {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(12.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top
            ) {


                Button(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(5.dp)),
                    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = lightGray2),
                    onClick = { expanded1 = true }) {
                    Row {
                        Text("$selectedItem1  ")
                        Icon(Icons.Default.ArrowDropDown, "")
                    }
                }
                DropdownMenu(
                    expanded = expanded1,
                    onDismissRequest = { expanded1 = false },
                ) {
                    itemList1.forEach {
                        DropdownMenuItem(
                            onClick = {
                                expanded1 = false
                                selectedItem1 = it
                            }
                        ) { Text(it) }
                    }
                }

                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp))

                Image(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp),
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_currency_exchange_96),
                    contentDescription = "exchange icon"
                )

                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp))

                Button(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(5.dp)),
                    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = lightGray2),
                    onClick = { expanded2 = true }) {
                    Row {
                        Text("$selectedItem2  ")
                        Icon(Icons.Default.ArrowDropDown, "")
                    }
                }


                DropdownMenu(
                    expanded = expanded2,
                    onDismissRequest = { expanded2 = false },
                ) {
                    itemList2.forEach {
                        DropdownMenuItem(
                            onClick = {
                                expanded2 = false
                                selectedItem2 = it
                            }
                        ) { Text(it) }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Try with removing ".fillMaxSize()" Column modifier property in DropDownMenu() compose function.

Comment: If this is a Constraint layout, do you have the top constraint set to 0. Sometimes on mine the top constraint will default to a triple digit. Take all constraints off the outline text that shows at the bottom. Then constrain it to the bottom of the drop box, then constrain the rest to parent. Withing the constraints in attributes you can change the line constraint by clicking the little line to change it.

Comment: okey thanks I fixed the textfield. now how can I fix dropdown menu. do you have any suggestion ?